# Define recipient depending on cell content

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I made a script that forwards emails to different people when clicking on a card button. This is the main part of the code:

```
function forwardtest() {
var threadsa = GmailApp.search('label: Inbox label: product-a');
for (var i = 0; i < threadsa.length; i++) {
var recipient = 'producta@gmail.com';
var messages = threadsa[i].getMessages();
for (var j = 0; j < messages.length; j++) {
  var body = messages[j].getBody();
  messages[j].forward(recipient,{htmlBody: body});
}
GmailApp.moveThreadToArchive(threadsa[i]);
}
var threadsb = GmailApp.search('label: Inbox label: product-b');
for (var i = 0; i < threadsb.length; i++) {
var recipient = 'productb@gmail.com';
var messages = threadsb[i].getMessages();
for (var j = 0; j < messages.length; j++) {
  var body = messages[j].getBody();
  messages[j].forward(recipient,{htmlBody: body});
}
GmailApp.moveThreadToArchive(threadsb[i]);
}
}
```

Sometimes, we'll need to change the forwarding addresses. Since I don't want people to change it directly in the code, I made a Google Sheets in which the forwarding addresses are listed depending on the email labels:

| Product label | Forward address |
| --- | --- |
| product-a | producta@gmail.com |
| product-b | productb@gmail.com |

Is there a way to replace the `var recipient = 'producta@gmail.com';` with "Look for the cell containing "product-a" content and define recipient as the content in the cell which is next to it"?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution:

Since you will be referencing a Google Sheet to fetch the data, you would need to use Sheets API starting from the [SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app) class. Also, since this script is not attached to the sheet from your use case, you would need to open the sheet by it's ID, which is in the URL link:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/<**SHEET-ID**>/edit#gid=0

Take note of the SHEET-ID since we will use it in the code.

For the code itself, I made a separate functions for finding the recipient and sending the emails for modularity:

**EDIT:** Rearranged the code, moved the function into a for loop instead.

```
function forwardtest() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SHEET-ID").getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var prodList = sheet.getRange(2,1,sheet.getLastRow()-1,2).getValues();

  for (var k = 0; k < prodList.length; k++) {
    var prod = prodList[k][0];
    var recipient = prodList[k][1];
    var threads = GmailApp.search('label: Inbox label: '+prod);
    for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
      var messages = threads[i].getMessages();
      for (var j = 0; j < messages.length; j++) {
        var body = messages[j].getBody();
        messages[j].forward(recipient,{htmlBody: body});
      }
    GmailApp.moveThreadToArchive(threads[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Note: Replace the SHEET-ID with the sheet ID from the URL.

**Sample Output:**

Using a sample table with a variable number of products:

[image]

**References:**

[Class SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app)

[Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet)

[Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)

Comment: Dear Carlos, thanks a lot for your great help, it works great!

Comment: Very much appreciated!

Comment: Hi again @Carlos M ! There's a case I did not think about: when there is a new product. In that case, one must go inside the code and add something like `forwardMail('product-c');` to `forwardMail('product-a');
  forwardMail('product-b');`. Would there be a way to update this code automatically when the user adds a product in the Google Sheet?

Comment: Thanks for bringing that out. I refactored the code to just use another loop instead of putting another function. Please check my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot again Carlos, it works like a charm! Can't be grateful enough to people like you who help total strangers on the internet.

Comment: Very much appreciated :)